# Jquery Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I can't figure out this scope issue:

```
var menuLinks = new Array("about.php", "contact.php");
function setClickListeners()
{
    for(var i=0; i<menuItems.length; i++)
    {
        $("#" + menuItems[i]).click( function () {
            window.alert(menuLinks[i]);
        });
    }
}
```

Notes: menuItems and menuLink is the same length.  This code is stripped down to make understanding it easier.

The outcome of this code when an item is clicked is an alert "undefined".  It should be the data from menuLinks.

Help!!!!

Frankie

Comment: The closure scope trap! Closures break in for loops like that. You need a `let`

Comment: Adding the code for `menuItems` might add a bit of clarity to your post.

Answer (score 8):

```
for (var i=0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
         $("#"+menuItems[i]).click(function() {
              alert(menuLinks[i]);
         });
    }(i));
}
```

You need to make the *current* value of `i` local to your anonymous function in `.click`.

JavaScript only has function scope. So if you don't make `i` local then whenever you press click the value of `i` is the *current* value which in this case is `menuItems.length - 1`.

What your doing above is creating a new functional scope and passing the value of `i` into it so that the current value of `i` stays constant in that function scope. That way your click function picks up the constant value of `i` from the closure.

**jslint**

Let's over complicate the code and satisfy jslint.

```
var wrapper = function(i) {
    $("#"+menuItems[i]).click(function() {
         alert(menuLinks[i]);
    });
};

for (var i=0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
    wrapper(i);
}
```

Comment: jsLint will however complain about making functions in a loop.

Comment: @david use jshint instead. It doesn't whine.

Comment: Any actual reason for a -1 or just jealousy/spite ?

Comment: The second version, using a pre-defined function is more efficient. Redefining and calling an anonymous function inside a loop is clever but not optimal. If the predifined function was called something more descriptive than wrapper, say `addMenuAction` the code would be more self explanatory too. The explanation of why a closure is needed is very clear so +1

Comment: @meduw that's a micro optimisation for any trivially small loop. Micro optimisations are evil. Whether it offers greater readability is argueable.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner code:

```
var menuLinks = new Array("about.php", "contact.php");
function setClickListeners()
{
    $.each(menuLinks, function(i, element)
    {
        $("#" + menuItems[i]).click( function (e) {
            alert(menuItems[i]);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Except menuLinks and menuItems are different ;) This doesn't do anything.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... try this! Remember that menuItems has to be declared about of the loop.